# Generating Thumbnails for video

Tags: videos, thumbnails, web-services

I have checked and read lot of post about one single issue that is far more complicated than it seems.

I have a website that uses a lot of videos taken from wwebsite as on the internet ^^ (services like youtube, vimeo, videobuzzy, etc) and we would like to generate on the fly a thumbnail of the embedded video.

Each service uses its own API so I should adapt code for each, which it far too much code and I could never manage every service.

A webserver propose something like that : http://embed.ly but I tried them and, as exemple, videos from videobuzzy doesn't work. So that's a partial solution.

Another solution would be to use a screenshot service that could request the video's URL, render it, take a snapshot and generate an image. Tempting, but results tends to add delays, and I have to find a snapshot service and generate the code (well, this could be the fun part).

The simpliest would be to take a screen capture and create an image ourselves, then upload it.

I would rather propose something more user-friendly but I have no more clue.

Is anyone has some advice on it and do I get the picture right ?

Thank you.

ADDENDUM **

If I could, instead of the thumbnails, just embed the video (usually an iframe) into a  with specific size, that could do the trick...

Comment: One way found was via a plugin: wordtube. Generally covering JW Player.. but maybe useful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the oEmbed functionality baked into WordPress. Typically any video host on this list will return a thumbnail to you using oembed.

Here is a list of default providers that WordPress uses for auto embedding in the content area. I've included non-video sources as well for the convenience of others.

- http://www.youtube.com/oembed
- http://blip.tv/oembed/
- http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.xml
- http://www.dailymotion.com/api/oembed/
- http://www.flickr.com/services/oembed/
- http://api.smugmug.com/services/oembed/
- http://www.hulu.com/api/oembed.xml
- http://lab.viddler.com/services/oembed/
- http://qik.com/api/oembed.xml
- http://revision3.com/api/oembed/
- http://photobucket.com/oembed
- http://photobucket.com/oembed
- http://www.scribd.com/services/oembed
- http://wordpress.tv/oembed/
- http://polldaddy.com/oembed/
- http://www.funnyordie.com/oembed

The full list of possible providers is documented at the WordPress codex under:
[Embeds -  Okay, So What Sites Can I Embed From?](https://wordpress.org/support/article/embeds/#okay-so-what-sites-can-i-embed-from)

Select your provider then use the following to get your video information.

```
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/class-oembed.php');
$oembed= new WP_oEmbed;
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0';
//As noted in the comments below, you can auto-detect the video provider with the following
$provider = $oembed->discover($url);
//$provider = 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed';
$video = $oembed->fetch($provider, $url, array('width' => 300, 'height' => 175));
$title = $video->title;
$html = $video->html;
$thumb = $video->thumbnail_url;
```

I realize VideoBuzzy is not on the list. It appears to be a YouTube knockoff site. You should ask them if they have oembed protocols. If they don't, you can register a non oembed handler by using [`wp_embed_register_handler()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sounds real nice ! But is there a quick way to get the $url from the post instead of beign hardcoded ?

Comment: Right now, i'm just using custom field to place my video url. Working nice, keep testing... Many thanks, Brian ! I just adapted the code by adding $provider = $oembed->discover($vid_url); so I don't need to hardcode the video provider

Comment: @Simon Can you share the final code that helped to implement this? And kindly give us some details on how to implement this? I have same requirements but not sure how to do this on WP, I'm still new to WP. Thanks

Comment: @Krunal Yes I could, it's pretty close to Brian's solution ! I just added a fallback image and update meta data if the oEmbed succeed, so I don't have to ask each time. But I don't how to send it to you, since i cannot add code in comments, and I don't feel it's worth an new answer ?

Comment: @Simon Paste your optimized solution in pastie.org and I'll add it to my edit. You can leave a link in the comment area.

Comment: @Brian : this is the pastie http://pastie.org/5166231 I just put the whole commented function. I use it to display for a post a preview based on either post attachment, image uri from a custom field or video url in the same custom field. Just hope it helps.

Comment: @Brian & Simon, that will be great, thanks. Any idea how to to do this for video embedded in content area of wp post?

Comment: @BrianFegter: Hey, any solution for self hosted videos? Or i have to use something like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @Sisir Actually, there is. You can look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler  Register a non-oEmbed handler first, then use the code above. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this plugin [Wordpress Video Plugin](http://www.daburna.de/blog/2006/12/13/wordpress-video-plugin/) and edit the code of this plugin and add the other sites in it.

OR

You have to integrate **FFMPEG** in wordpress.

Comment: Thank you, I'd rather avoid using plugins when I can avoid it ^^

Comment: @Simon It was meant as a reference: Go into the files "_and edit the code of this plugin". :)

Comment: @kaiser -yes, you're right, the plugin code should provide insight and working implementation ^^