# Bypassing a Form Options

Tags: custom-field, forms

here is the situation. I am using a plugin and although it is (half) works, I can't access the setting page.

The plugin is to fetch thumbnail from Youtube and other video sites, but the problem is, I have to embed the video using a specific "Featured" box, for aesthetic reason. It works well if I just put the video inside the post, the "usual way".

I've done some research and apparently the plugin accept custom field value (which can solve my problem) but I have to put the custom fields name in its setting page. For some reason, I can't access it and only get a blank page. I think it may be a plugin conflict but I've tried activate and deactivate the others and still no luck.

I look at the code and found this part:

```
<th scope="row">Custom Field (Optional: If your video is stored in a custom field, enter the name of that field here. Otherwise, leave this field blank.)</th> 
    <td><fieldset><legend class="screen-reader-text"><span>Custom Field (Optional: If your video is stored in a custom field, enter the name of that field here. Otherwise, leave this field blank.)</span></legend> 
    <input name="video_thumbnails_custom_field" type="text" id="video_thumbnails_custom_field" value="<?php echo get_option( 'video_thumbnails_custom_field' ); ?>" />
```

and I believe this is where it uses the input from the form:

```
// Get the post or custom field to search
        if ( $video_key = get_option( 'video_thumbnails_custom_field' ) ) {
            $markup = get_post_meta( $post_id, $video_key, true );
        } else {
            $post_array = get_post( $post_id );
            $markup = $post_array->post_content;
            $markup = apply_filters( 'the_content', $markup );
        }
        $new_thumbnail = null;
```

My question is, how do I bypass and just hardcoded my custom field name? I've tried assigning the value directly to $video_key (so it is $video_key = $skyali_video >> the theme's video featured's value) and variations of putting the custom field's name ("skyali_video") but still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the oEmbed API to grab the video image on the fly.

Check out my answer here:
[Generating Thumbnails for video](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40846/generating-thumbnails-for-video)