# WordPress 5.3.x YouTube oEmbed is not working

Tags: oembed, youtube

We followed [Brian Fegter's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40868/22728) to display YouTube videos using WordPress' oEmbed feature:

```
// Public video.
$video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lODe0i7dNw';

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-wp-oembed.php');
$oembed = new WP_oEmbed;

// Auto-detect the video provider with the following
$provider = $oembed->discover($video_url);

$video = $oembed->fetch($provider, $video_url);

echo $video->html;
```

The code worked earlier. But right now it's not working. We're using WordPress 5.3.2. We tried updating WordPress to 5.3.6, but no luck.

The main issue is: `$oEmbed->discover()` cannot detect any provider and returning `false`. :(

You can see the issue live at [this link](http://iptv.imagecolorist.com/video/dragon-fruit-becomes-hugely-popular-in-bangladesh/). (For some time, we're showing some of the debug information, if you need them)

[image: Debug information]

Comment: I'd guess you want something other than discover() - maybe get_provider, or something on the WP_Embed class instead that caches the result in post meta.

Comment: And there's [`wp_oembed_get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_oembed_get/) if you just want to get the HTML/embed code. Have you tried using that function?

Comment: Your debug information lists `Provdier` as not being found... ...double check any code pertaining to this for typos.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you so much. That worked like a charm. <3 But I also tried `echo do_shortcode('[embed]' . esc_url($video_url) . '[/embed]');`, it didn't work. If you answer the question with this solution, I can accept it as an 'accepted answer'. But that still be a mystery to me, what's happening inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently the issue also happens in WordPress 5.6 (the latest release as of writing), and YouTube is probably at fault because the (oEmbed) `<link>` tags are in the *`body`* instead of the `head` (see screenshot below), and that in turn causes the issue because [`WP_oEmbed::discover()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_oembed/discover/) looks for the `<link>` tags in the `head` *only*. And secondly, YouTube uses `http://` instead of `https://` (secure protocol) in the `<link>` tags, so you would need to replace that `http://` with `https://` if your site uses `https://` or is SSL-enabled.

**Screenshot 1: Elements inspector tab (in Chrome)**

[image: Chrome DevTools]

**Screenshot 2: Server-generated HTML source (press `Ctrl+U` on Chrome)**

[image: Chrome view-source]

And maybe (YouTube is not at fault and) the WordPress core team should revise the function so that it tries to also search in the `body`? Or perhaps use a better way to find the tags like using [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) ...?

But anyway, as mentioned by [@Rup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3276/rup), you could alternatively use `WP_oEmbed::get_provider()` which will load the sanctioned/trusted oEmbed providers defined in the class [constructor](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_oembed/__construct/), and (as of writing) YouTube is actually the very first in the providers list.

```php
// So instead of:
// this fetches the <link> tags from the provider site
$provider = $oembed->discover( $video_url );

// Use this one:
// this finds in the sanctioned oEmbed providers first
// then tries with the above discover()..
$provider = $oembed->get_provider( $video_url );
```

Or as I said in the comments, if you just wanted to get the HTML/embed code, then you could simply use [`wp_oembed_get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_oembed_get/) which should work since, although indirectly, the function uses [`WP_oEmbed::get_data()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_oembed/get_data/) which uses `WP_oEmbed::get_provider()`:

```php
// I'd prefer this:
echo wp_oembed_get( $video_url );

// But that is equivalent to:
$video = $oembed->get_data( $video_url );
echo $video->html;

// And that is equivalent to:
$provider = $oembed->get_provider( $video_url );
$video = $oembed->fetch( $provider, $video_url );
echo $video->html;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. BTW I also tried HTTP with the shortcode but found no luck. Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: Note that the Codex [says](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embed_Shortcode#Usage), "*This shortcode isn't enabled until 'the_content' filter has been processed at least once.*", so perhaps you just need to use `$GLOBALS['wp_embed']->run_shortcode( 'Content with [embed] shortcode' );` or `apply_filters( 'the_content', 'Content with [embed] shortcode' )`?

Comment: And actually, that "http" thing, I meant to replace it with `https` in the (YouTube) *provider* URL, not the video URL.. :)

Comment: Thank you so much <3